# What is protobuf.meta in android apk?

Tags: android, apk, android-support-library

I recently updated my codebase to use v27.0.2 libraries from v25.1.0 and started seeing a "protobuf.meta" file in my apk. Anyone knows what this is for? Is there a way to remove this from the release apk and will there be any bad consequences if i do so?

[image: apk analyzer image after updating to support lib version 27.0.2]

Answer (score 2):

**`protobuf.meta`** i.e [**`Protocol Buffers`**](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview)

> Protocol buffers are a flexible, efficient, automated mechanism for
>   serializing structured data – think XML, but smaller, faster, and
>   simpler. You define how you want your data to be structured once, then
>   you can use special generated source code to easily write and read
>   your structured data to and from a variety of data streams and using a
>   variety of languages. You can even update your data structure without
>   breaking deployed programs that are compiled against the "old" format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not able to figure out what's it doing in my final apk. I am not using anything related to protobuf directly in the code.

Comment: @AmitBarjatya Don't worry about it. It's auto-generated.

Comment: Auto-generated by who? for what reason?